# How to get a substring from an inconsistent list of strings?

Tags: python

I have an array:

```py
my_array = [
'034538 Plot 34 01.01.2018',
'0243432_4540343_Plots 83-90_04/01/2019',
'2028011_Block_B_01-01-2019',
]
```

Expected output:

```py
‘Plot 34’,
‘Plots 83-90’,
‘Block B’
```

How can I get the plot/block information? I'm having trouble since the delimiters before the Plot/Plots information is different

Comment: As I said in my old answer: I'd go the regex route. I don't have enough meaningful information to build a working one (are "Plot", "Plots", and "Block" the only keywords? Are the seperators for each keyword consistend??). Otherwise I'd suggest checking for the existence of "Plots", "Block", and "Plot" and handle each case seperately

Comment: Can you please build a rejex code for me since I’m unfamiliar with it. The separators are inconsistent in each caze

Comment: What does "inconsistent separator" means, in literal sense?

Comment: @okeyiaj No, I really can't. If I don't know what the seperators are I can't feed them into a regex

Comment: `-+.*Plot\s(\d{2}).*_Plots\s(\d*)-(\d*).*_Block_(.)`   type of regexp would do in your case, but if the separators ACTUALLY differ, you need to make few different regexp cases and test which regexp version returns all your needed values properly.

Answer (score 2):

Since separators are inconsitent, it is easier to write a if/else construct:

```
for item in my_array:
    _start, _stop = 0, 0
    if 'Plots' in item:
        _start = item.find('Plots')
        # We are searching for the next underscore after Plots + 1 character!
        _stop = item.find('_', _start + 1 + 5)
    elif 'Plot' in item:
        _start = item.find('Plot')
        _stop = item.find(' ', _start + 1 + 4)
    elif 'Block' in item:
        _start = item.find('Block')
        _stop = item.find('_', _start + 1 + 5)
    else:
        pass  # doing nothing
    print (item[_start:_stop])
```

Prints:

```
Plot 34
Plots 83-90
Block_B
```

Answer (score 0):

you can detect the front and back separator for your target strings (Plot/Plots/Block), split by this separators and then extract the desired output:

```
import re

my_array = [
'034538 Plot 34 01.01.2018',
'0243432_4540343_Plots 83-90_04/01/2019',
'2028011_Block_B_01-01-2019',
]

TARGET_STR = {'Plot', 'Block', 'Plots'}

def detect_separators(my_str):
    """Detect front/back separtor"""

    for target in TARGET_STR:
        if target in my_str:
            target_index = my_str.index(target)
            front_separator = my_str[target_index - 1]
            back_separtor = my_str[target_index + len(target)]
            return front_separator, back_separtor, target_index


for item in my_array:
    front_separator, back_separtor, start_index  = detect_separators(item)
    print(*re.split(f'{front_separator}|{back_separtor}', item[start_index:])[:2])
```

output:

```
Plot 34
Plot  83-90
Block B
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` with `re.findall`:

```
import re
def extract(d):
   return re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+\s[\w\-]+', re.sub('_+', ' ', d))[0]

result = list(map(extract, my_array))
```

Output:

```
['Plot 34', 'Plots 83-90', 'Block B']
```